# Spring 4.1.1 META-INF/spring.factories for Unit Testing

Tags: spring, spring-test

With Spring 4.1.1, I was under the impression that if I added a `META-INF/spring.factories` properties file with the name of a Spring interface (specifically in this case `org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener`) to my `module/JAR` that the file would be detected at runtime, and my implementation of the T`estExecutionListener` would be invoked.  However, I'm unable to get this instantiated.  Beyond creating the spring.factories file, do I need to do anything else to my spring XML config in order to have Spring scan for these files?

I set a breakpoint in `SpringFactoriesLoader`, but I only see one call to that class (for the `BeanInfoFactory`) and I don't see any other calls - I at least expected to see an invocation for the provided `spring.factories` file in `spring-test`.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing everything correctly. So, assuming that you have `META-INF/spring.factories` in your classpath and assuming you are using `spring-test` 4.1.0 or higher, it should work. Spring Security in fact already uses this mechanism successfully. If you are still running into issues, please create a repro project and a corresponding JIRA issue (https://jira.spring.io). Thanks, Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: Regarding debugging `SpringFactoriesLoader`, the `AbstractTestContextBootstrapper` in the `spring-test` module invokes `SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames()` (i.e., _not_ the `loadFactories()` method).

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: No we were not - we took the alternative approach of defining another common base test class and add the annotation on the class - we gave up on the SPI approach.

Comment: In my case it works, the file is located in `src\test\java\META-INF\spring.factories` and contains one line `org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener=de.xxx.yyy.CustomTestExecutionListener`